# image is not shown in email in cakephp 3.5

Tags: php, image, cakephp-3.0

Images are not shown in email templates in cakephp 3.5.

In ctp file:

```
<img src="<?php echo $link_img; ?>" alt="Activate Account"/>
```

In Controller:

```
$email->viewVars(['url' => $url, 'username' => $username,'logo' => $logo_img_link,'link_img' => $link_img_url]);
```

Comment: What does `$link_img` contain, is that a full absolute URL? Are you testing this in an actual mail client? (Then you might have to instruct that to show external images in the first place, because for privacy reasons that is usually not the default.)

Comment: https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/NZRFlPqxDqy2CDGfM-Zx69vUrqvTBnGXmzYwqYf4W8-GdQdteHMEZoobUL8rTJABrd0gnHgL9Q59eQQW32Po9DMoEZi4nJItsUAZ2Gg2ANY=s0-d-e1-ft#http://192.168.1.192/meteornow_gazoo/public_html/img/logo.png
in My mail shown like this image url

Comment: I am not sure what exactly that is supposed to be, but seeing as it ends in `http://192.168.1.192/meteornow_gazoo/public_html/img/logo.png` – you can not really expect that to work on the internet, if you use a local IP …

Comment: $logo_img_link = $this->getapiUrl()."/img/logo.png";  

   
This is do it for generate the full url for image

Comment: Are you only testing this on a local server? It would presumably have to be reachable on the public internet for this too work. Many mail providers with web interfaces don’t show images from the original referred location, but proxy the requests via their own servers - that of course can’t work, if your image is not publicly reachable to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Try uploading the image on a server and providing its path in your mail template:

```
<img src="https://yourdomain.com/images/emailer/fb.png" alt="Activate Account"/>
```

Comment: The image url generates correctly. but the image not loaded